# How to Find an Exact Directory Name Using findstr

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory, findstr

I am trying to use findstr to find an exact name of a folder. As an example, let's say I'm looking for a folder called Example in a directory called Example Folders. The problem is; findstr is showing results for all folder's containing the the name Example (i.e. Example, Example 1, Example One, etc.)

I've tried the following:

```
dir "%SystemDrive%\Example Folders" | findstr /C:"Example"
```

Which returns these results:

- Example
- Example 1
- Example One

And This:

```
dir "%SystemDrive%\Example Folders" | findstr /X "Example"
```

Which returns no results.

I've also tried a number of variations with different switches, beginning and end of word positions, beginning and end of line positions, and regular and literal expressions, all to no avail.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use PowerShell instead of `cmd.exe`.

Comment: `dir /B /A:D "%SystemDrive%\Example Folders" | findstr /I /X "Example"`?

Comment: Use the `/I` `/B` and `/E` options with `FINDSTR`.

Comment: On a side note seems like it would be much easier to use an `IF EXIST` command. `IF EXIST "%SystemDrive%\Example Folders\Example\" echo Found it`

Comment: @Squashman, that seems to be the intent here. It should be noted that the trailing backslash is an important distinction to ensure that only a directory is matched.

Comment: In answer to your question, did you try a literal ending match `| FindStr /LE "\Example"`